# Magento 2 Product Images / Add to Cart / Variations not Loading

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions, ajax, product-view-page

I had tried to install a **new extension**. And in the set up it told me to **disable the cache**. Which i did.

I installed it and it seemed like everything was ok (*loading slow*) but the following issues occured.

> - Images on Product View Page were not showing
> - Configurations on Product View Page were not showing
> - Add to cart would hang (run ajax symbol indefinitely)
> - Description / More Information text was merged.

I uninstalled the app. Through SSH deleted the files ran setup / compile / cleared cache / reindexed / deployed static content /Re Enabled Cache. All of which completed successfully.

I don't know where to check for errors. If someone can please help. [image: Ajax Spinning Symbol indefinitely]

Comment: Check console error

Comment: Which extension was it? Did you managed to solve the issue. I am facing similar issue